# Excel Find difference between rows

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, powerquery

I have a project with different data in general.The data is split on 2 columns. On Column A I have number and on Column B I have Labels. What I'm trying to find is the common part on the rows for each label.
For example:

```
A1:52340
A2:5234
A3:523456788994
A4:5235
A6:52356
A7:523567651781
```

The data in column B is the same for A1-A7. The result should be 5234 for A1-A3 and 5235 for A4-A7. I would do this by hand but I have about 50k rows and this is a simple example to show what i want to achieve. Is there a way I can get the result I want?

Comment: Show a sample of your data if you can please

Comment: Here's a short example, I manually inserted the data in Column C. !https://i.imgur.com/Af8wFQk.jpg

Comment: Is it always the first 4 digits?

Comment: It's not always 4, it can be more, up to 7. But it also cand be a unique number which doesn't have nothing in common with any other so...it shouldn't show anything then.

Comment: Yeah I think it's possible. You would need a loop through rows, which would compare the current row to the previous row and next row inside of another loop which would grab 1,2,3...n characters from the `Left` and the loop would go until characters of previous row or next row differ: so if the current row was unique it would fail at the first character, if the current row was similar to previous but different from next etc. etc.

Comment: I suggest you to add `#powerquery` and `#vba` to your post as it is a bit complicated to solve it using formula and it will take a long time to calculate the result given that you have 50k plus rows of data. I will work on a **power-query** based solution for you.

Comment: You need to explain the rule in more detail.  For example why isn't the answer `523` for range `A1-A7`? Or `52346` for range `A6-A7`?

Comment: @chrisneilsen from previous comment the common root is limited to **4 to 7 characters** so it will not be `523` for range `A1-A7`; I presume `52356` is not the root because of the presence of `5235` in A4.

Comment: @Terry You're guessing, I'd rather hear from the OP...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> **Formula Based Solution**

Please note I have created a sample list of **Acc. No** just to test different scenarios. In order to solve the problem I have to use a few **helper columns**.

The logic is to:

1. Lay out the potential common root for each **Acc. No** with character length from 4 to 7. The formula used is `=LEFT([Acc. No],N) where N is from 4 to 7`;
2. Find out if a given common root at a particular character length has occurred more than once, starting from 7-Character list working backwards towards 4-Character list. The function used is **COUNTIF**;
3. An important rule is that **if the occurrence of a 6-Character common root is the same as the occurrence of the corresponding 7-Character common root, overwrite the occurrence to 0**, and apply this rule between `5-Character with 6-Character`, and between `4-Character with 5-Character`. The function used is **IF**;
4. For a specific **Acc. No**, whichever common root has the **most occurrence**, it will be the correct common root for that **Acc. No**.
5. If an **Acc. No** only appeared once in the list, it has no common root as mentioned by OP in the comment.

Here are the formulas in the first row of each helper column, please adjust to suit your case:

Cell C2: `=LEFT($A2,C$1)` finding 7-Character common root

Cell D2: `=LEFT($A2,D$1)` finding 6-Character common root

Cell E2: `=LEFT($A2,E$1)` finding 5-Character common root

Cell F2: `=LEFT($A2,F$1)` finding 4-Character common root

Cell G2: `=COUNTIF(C$2:C$21,C2)` finding the occurrence of the 7-Character common root

Cell H2: `=IF(COUNTIF(D$2:D$21,D2)=COUNTIF(C$2:C$21,C2),0,COUNTIF(D$2:D$21,D2))` finding the occurrence of the 6-Character common root and if it is same as **G2**, overwrite it as `0`

Cell I2: `=IF(COUNTIF(E$2:E$21,E2)=COUNTIF(D$2:D$21,D2),0,COUNTIF(E$2:E$21,E2))` finding the occurrence of the 5-Character common root and if it is same as **H2**, overwrite it as `0`

Cell J2: `=IF(COUNTIF(F$2:F$21,F2)=COUNTIF(E$2:E$21,E2),0,COUNTIF(F$2:F$21,F2))` finding the occurrence of the 4-Character common root and if it is same as **I2**, overwrite it as `0`

Cell K2: `=IF(SUM(G2:J2)=1,"",LEFT(A2,INDEX(C$1:F$1,,MATCH(MAX(G2:J2),G2:J2,0))))` find out the common with the most occurrence and overwrite is as blank cell if the occurrence is `1`

[image: Formulas]

P.s. I have also developed a **Power Query** solution using the same logic as above. It will take some time to compose the answer so I shared the formula-based solution as a start. Please do let me know how long it will take for you to run the formula-based solution on your 50k plus data-set. Cheers :)

Comment: This works awesome and does exactly what I needed it to do. Also is fast, didn't stuck even for a second. Thank you.

Comment: @misc15 good to know that it worked for you, and a little bit surprise to know that it is working efficiently on 50k rows of data. I suggest you to keep an eye on any potential error or irregularities and do let me know if you have encountered any. Btw, if you are happy with the formula based solution, I will probably not post the power query solution which is essentially the same as the formula based one but just calculated within the query editor. It would take a big chunk of time to write that approach up...